# Add key/value pair to existing array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects that is saved into a userList useState which is composed of:

```
[{
    firstName: "blah" 
    lastName: "blah2"
 }

 {
    firstName: "test"
    lastName: "test2"
}]
```

I have a useEffect that calls a function and returns a value. I want to store a new key and value to each user in userList.

```
useEffect(() => {

        userList.forEach((user, index) =>
            returnNewValueForNewKeyFunction(user, index).then(newValue => {

                userList[index]['newKey'] = newValue
                //this console.log shows new field and value
                console.log(userList)
                //this console.log ALSO shows new field and value
                console.log(JSON.stringify(contactList[index]))
            })
        )
    }
}, [])
```

This is fine if I'm operating out of console.log, but unfortunately I need to render the data onto the page.. in my render I have:

```
return (
    <TableBody>
        {userList
            .map((user, index) => (
                 <TableRow>
                     <TableCell>
                         {user.newKey}
                     </TableCell>
)
```

user.newKey is showing as blank and it seems like the user wasn't updated at all. How can I make it so the value is actually updated and can be read from when rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt mutate your list, you should use useState to store your list, so something like this :

```
const [ state, setState] = useState(userList);
```

Then when you want to update, do something like this :

```
const listCopy = [...state];
//Logic to update your list here
listCopy[index][otherindex] = Value;
setState(listCopy)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the help! this worked. in case anyone is looking at this in the future, i used 'newKey' instead of [otherIndex] and newValue instead of value.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying your `userList` but not calling your `set` function on which means React won't know to re-render with the updated state.

Instead of mutating the current state, you should create a new array and then call the `set` function returned by `useState` with the updated array after making your changes.

It also looks like your `returnNewValueForNewKeyFunction` is a promise / `async` which means each of your item changes are happening `async`. You'll need to make these synchronous / wait for them all before updating your state to make your state change a single update for the UI.

E.g., putting these both together - if you are doing:

```
const [userList, setUserList] = useState();
```

You could do:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Since can't use an async func directly with useEffect -
    // define an async func to handle your updates and call it within the useEffect func
    const updateUsers = async () => {
        // Create a new array for your updated state
        const updatedUserList = [];

        // Loop over your values inline so your can await results to make them sync
        for (let index = 0; index < userList.length; index ++) {
            const user = userList[index];
            const newVal = await returnNewValueForNewKeyFunction(user, index);

            // Create a shallow copy of the original value and add the newValue
            updatedUserList[index] = { ...user, newKey: newValue };
            // ... Any other logic you need
        }

        // Call set with the updated value so React knows to re-render
        setUserList(updatedUserList);
    };

    // Trigger your async update
    updateUsers();
}, [])
```